# Pagination not working properly (php/ajax)

Tags: php, ajax

I want to add pagination to my page using ajax. I don't know why but php/ajax links doesn't work.

After hovering '2' I have `localhost/site-test/public/staff/index.php?page=2`, after click - nothing happens.

[image]

[image]

**1. load_data.php**

```
<?php

$current_page = !empty($_POST['page']) ? (int)$_POST['page'] : '1';

// number links 1.2.3.....
for($i=1; $i <= $limit; $i++) {

    echo "<span class='pagination_link  id='" . $i . "'><a href=\"{$url}?page=" . $i . "\">{$i}</a></span>";

}
?>
```

**2. index.php**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    load_data();

    function load_data(page) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "load_data.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          page: page
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('.load_data').html(data);
        }
      })
    }

  });
    $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var page = $(this).attr("id"); 
        load_data(page);

        return event.preventDefault();

    });

</script>
```

Comment: where is your `filter_data` function declared?

Comment: Where is `filter_data()`?

Comment: @Nishanth Matha my mistake I was making a mistake it is 'load_data'

Comment: in load_data.php you aren't using the `$_POST['page']` value which you passed in your ajax

Comment: @Nishanth Matha 
$current_page = !empty($_POST['page']) ? (int)$_POST['page'] : '1';

Comment: why is your index.php only javascript?

Comment: @Oli pagination in php works, but i don't know why it doesn't work with ajax. If you want I can put all the code from index.php

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I just added:

Work this

```
echo "<a class='pagination_link' href='#' id='".$i."'>{$i}</a>";

or this

echo "<span class='pagination_link page-link' style='cursor:pointer;' id='" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</span>";
```